# facebook-c#-sdk rendering unwanted html tags

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get a simple facebook application to work, based on the downloaded example projects.  The code prints some javascript code which makes perfect sense.  The problem is it wraps it in a  tag, and also prints a body tag.  These things mess up facebook fbml apps, so that when I try to run the application through facebook I get this error:

FBML Error (line 3): illegal tag "body" under "fb:canvas"Sorry, the application you were using is experiencing a problem. Please try again later.

When viewing the source I can see that the problem is the injected html and body tags.  Am I doing something wrong?  How do I get the sdk to print the javascript without printing these extra tags?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First off, the Facebook C# SDK does not support FBML applications. Facebook is deprecating FBML. I would strongly suggest building an iFrame app if possible. That being said, the Facebook C# SDK has nothing to do with the html markup. Simply remove the html markup from your master page.

You should be able to get the Facebook C# SDK working with FBML, but again we do not support it and I would not recommend spending time developing a new app on a technology that is being deprecated.